# Are there limits to cloudfront cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

In cloudfront I can set the amount of time before an image expires from cache.  Are there limitations to this?  Can I have 500 files(example) set to stay in cache for 1yr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no restrictions. You can cache files up until 2038 if you want. Although practically, I would find it hard to believe that a file would last that long on an endpoint.

You can cache as many files as you want for as long as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are limits.

I'll summarize a few:

Just fyi, invalidating is quick but their documentation states 10-15 minutes
Also, if you dig deeper, EDGES may hold the data up to 24hours, not necessarily serving it.

It currently states that you have 1000 Objects limit
Objects can be as simple as /mystats.json?user=124  , each query string can be treated as an object.

Max of 4000 characters for the object name.